# Trying to grab a value using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, stock

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.gurufocus.com/dcf/AMZN'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
div = soup.find(id='result')

print (div)
```

The result is:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

when in fact a value exists within the `div`.

I don't know enough about Python or BS to pull that value and would appreciate any help

Comment: There isn't any value between the tag, check the source code of the page.

Comment: That `#result` field is populated by javascript which means you can't use BS to get it. You can try to check how it is calculated or try selenium driver that can render page with javascript.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness there is for me though, however I assume that might be due to JavaScript code exeecuting.

Comment: Also, I'm getting 403 Forbidden when using urllib for that.

Comment: Looks like the value might be added on the client side (js for instance) and you should use something to render it first, like `selenium`

Comment: true that rendering it is an option, however I'd rather go for an API if it exists, or using an alternative resource. You'll make your life easier

Comment: I'll look into selenium, thanks.  I've tried finding an API that provides this value but am unable to locate one.  In fact, I can only find two sites that generate this value for all stocks and am having the same issue with both. Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: Instead of selenium you can use a proxy which will render the js and give the source code. Try scraperapi . Or proxycrawl, apify. https://www.scraperapi.com/documentation